# In Animate CC how to load an image dynamically

Tags: html5-canvas, animate-cc

Creating an Intro in Animate CC and I have to load images dynamically fetching the image source from a Json file. img source is driven dynamically from .net to Json. there is no click event. image will be in any format. I am not a coder. please help me.